# I have to show that this function is continuous

Tags: continuity, expected-value, weak-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Let $U:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ be a continuous functions such that $[0,1]$ can be partitioned into a finite no. of intervals such that $U(\cdot)$ is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing or constant  in each of these intervals. $\mu$ is a probability measure on $[0,1]$. It need not be continuous.

I have to show that $\mathbb{E}(x|U(x) \leq u)$ is continuous at $u$ if $\mu(\{U(x)=u\})=0$.

I tried with distributional convergence. I think it can be easily shown that, due to the fact that $\{U(x) \leq u\}$ consists of a finite no. of intervals, $\mu|_{\{U(x) \leq u+\epsilon\}} \implies \mu|_{\{U(x) \leq u\}}$, i.e. distributional convergence if $\mu(\{U(x)=u\})=0$. Then we can use continuity of the expectation operator  to conclude. But I'm getting confused trying to show distributional convergence.

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $P(U(x) \leq u) > 0$, otherwise the expectation isn't well defined.

We will also need property that $P(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^\infty A_i) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} P(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^n A_n)$, so $$\lim\limits_{\varepsilon \to 0}P\left(U^{-1}((u - \varepsilon, u]\right) =
\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}P\left(U^{-1}(u - \frac{1}{n}, u]\right) =\\
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}P\left(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^n U^{-1}(u - \frac{1}{i}, u]\right) =\\
P\left(\bigcap\limits_{i = 1}^\infty U^{-1}(u - \frac{1}{i}, u]\right) =\\
P\left(U^{-1}(\{u\}\right)
$$
And similarly $\lim\limits_{\varepsilon \to 0} P(U^{-1}((u, u + \varepsilon)) = P(U^{-1}(\varnothing)) = 0$.

By law of total expectation,
$$\mathbb E(x | U(x) \leq u) =
\mathbb E(x | U(x) \leq u - \varepsilon) \cdot
\frac{P(U(x) \leq u - \varepsilon)}{P(U(x) \leq u)} +
\mathbb E(x | u - \varepsilon < U(x) \leq u) \cdot
\frac{P(u - \varepsilon < U(x) \leq u)}{P(U(x) \leq u)}$$

$\mathbb E(x | u - \varepsilon < U(x) \leq u)$ is bounded, $P(u - \varepsilon < U(x) \leq u) \to 0$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$, $\frac{P(U(x) \leq u - \varepsilon)}{P(U(x) \leq u)} \to 1$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$, so we necessary have
$$\lim\limits_{\varepsilon \to 0+} \mathbb E(x | U(x) \leq u - \varepsilon) = \mathbb E(x | U(x) \leq u)$$

Similarly,
$$E(x | U(x) \leq u + \varepsilon) = E(x | U(x) \leq u) \cdot \frac{P(U(x) \leq u)}{P(U(x) \leq u + \varepsilon)} +
E(x | u < U(x) \leq u + \varepsilon) \cdot \frac{P(u < U(x) \leq u + \varepsilon)}{P(u \leq U(x) + \varepsilon)}$$

And again, right part goes to $E(x|U(x) \leq u)$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$, so left part does it too.

Comment: Thank you so much! A couple of questions: 1. Because $\mu(\{U(x)=u\})=0, P(u-\varepsilon<U(x) \leq u) \rightarrow 0$ as $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0, \frac{P(U(x) \leq u-\varepsilon)}{P(U(x) \leq u)} \rightarrow 1$ as $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$, right? 2. And the analogous limit in the second part follows  from the right-continuity of the $\operatorname{CDF}$ of $U(x)$, derived from $\mu$, at $u$, right? 3. We  didn't need the "regularity" condition on $U$, and \textit{didn't even need continuity} of $U$, right?

Comment: 1. Right. 2. It's probably equivalent to this continuity, but essentially we need that as set decreases to empty set, probability of getting into it decreases to $0$. 3. Right, this would work with any (measurable) $U$.

Comment: Let $F_U(\cdot)$ be the derived CDF of $U(x)$ based on $\mu$, i.e. $F(u)=\mathbb{P}(U(x) \leq u)\;\forall\;u$. So if I understand correctly, the edited part that you added is equivalent to saying $\lim\limits_{\varepsilon \downarrow 0}F_U(u-\varepsilon)=F_U(u)$ (which holds because $\mu(U(x)=u)=0$) and $\lim\limits_{\varepsilon \downarrow 0}F_U(u+\varepsilon)=F_U(u)$, which is true for any CDF due to right continuity. Is this understanding of the edited part correct?

Comment: Yes, indeed it is more elegant to think about $P(U(x) \leq u)$ as CDF.